# How to convert bytes1 to int8 in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I tried casting a `bytes1` variable `y` to `int8` by:

`int8 x = int8(y);`

but it says:

```
Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes1" to "int8".
```

Both the types take 1 byte of space, so why is this not allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with version 0.8.0 the Solidity compiler only allows you to do one conversion at a time and what you are trying to do requires two: converting fixed bytes to an integer and then an unsigned integer to a signed one. You need to perform both conversions explicitly:

```
int8 x = int8(uint8(y));
```

Comment: Thanks, linking the 0.8.0 breaking changes here in case anyone is interested: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/breaking/080-breaking-changes.html

Comment: Let me just say, @foo, that I really appreciate the link to that changelog.  The main narrative for type conversions is completely deficient and doesn't even give examples of the kind of thing that this describes as being broken.  This changelog is the only place I have seen anything like a precise description of what conversions do.